# why CGContextDrawPDFPage( ctx, page1 ) takes 7 sec to draw a shadow pdf

Tags: ios

I notice in my app, there is one pdf is used as a multi layer shadow given by UE, and when I call `CGContextDrawPDFPage( ctx, page1 );`, it takes 7.8 sec to render, totally unacceptable. But I have no way to fix it. Looking for help, thanks so much!!

The pdf I have attached at https://github.com/liuxuan30/badPDF/blob/master/table_shadow.pdf

Comment: It does took huge amount of CPU to render it in Quick Look

Comment: then what's the problem...